# Does the self-contained version of fastlane support dev builds?

Tags: plugins, fastlane

When using the version of fastlane installed from Homebrew, I don't know how to use a development build of a plugin. I see `fastlane add_plugin` still generates a Pluginfile. If I try adding `gem "fastlane-plugin-xxx", git: "https://github.com/yyy/xxx"` or something similar using a `:path` argument, it always tries to install the version from RubyGems.

I have two specific cases where this makes things inconvenient:

1. I'm building a new plugin for a client. I want mobile devs to review it internally before it is published.
2. A user reported an error from a published plugin. I want them to try a dev version from the master branch in order to get more information.

In both cases, I think it's necessary to use Ruby and the Bundler. Not everyone has lots of Ruby experience, so getting someone set up can be an obstacle.

#### Edited 2017-07-06:

Part of the answer is obvious. When you run `fastlane add_plugin`, it prompts you if it cannot find the gem:

```
[jdee@Jimmy-Dees-MacBookPro TestApp]$ fastlane add_plugin my_new_action
[10:46:28]: Seems like the plugin is not available on RubyGems, what do you want to do?
1. Git URL
2. Local Path
3. RubyGems.org ('fastlane-plugin-my_new_action' seems to not be available there)
?
```

This works well with the fastlane gem, e.g. with RVM:

```
gem install fastlane
fastlane add_plugin my_new_action
```

The self-contained binary from Homebrew also prompts you for a Git URL or a local path, but I consistently get build failures from native extensions in the json gem on OS X Sierra. This may be due to plugin dependencies, but I'm not sure. This can still be a little awkward for the use cases above, and I'm surprised that this fails with the self-contained version, which I'd expect to be more robust than using Ruby. At least this removes the need for bundle install and bundle exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is basically that the self-contained version of Fastlane does not really work with plugins. In particular, when `fastlane add_plugin` or `fastlane install_plugins` runs `bundle install`, it tries to install the json gem, a dependency of the fastlane gem, which has native dependencies, and it cannot find `<stdio.h>`, presumably because `/usr/include` is screened out in the self-contained bundle in order to insulate it from the system Ruby. After this, you can run `bundle install` and `bundle exec` yourself, but in general a Gemfile is required to work with Fastlane plugins. The CLI will even tell you to run `bundle exec` once you have a Gemfile.

When using the `fastlane` gem, `fastlane add_plugin` will usually work, but again you will have a Gemfile and want to run `bundle exec fastlane` afterward.

You can just modify your Pluginfile to use a path or a git repo and rerun `bundle install`. There's not a much easier way to do this at the moment.